# Alignment of html controls

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Suppose I have following html:

```
 <div class="column col-sm-2 col-xs-2 col-md-3">


        <div class="row" style="margin-left: 10px;">
            <p><b>Test:</b>
                <select>
                    <option>test1</option>
                    <option>test2</option>
                    <option>test3</option>

                </select>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="margin-left: 10px;">
            <p><b>LongLineTest:</b>
                <select>
                    <option>test1</option>
                    <option>test2</option>
                    <option>test3</option>
                </select>

            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

It produces somthing like:

```
  Test:select control

  LongLineTest:select control
```

But I need the following alignment:

```
        Test:select control

LongLineTest:select control
```

How can I do this? Also I'm using bootstrap framework.
Here is  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wsh58zb6/).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read the bootstrap docs. Specifically [horizontal forms](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal)

Comment: Pretty sure you shouldn't be wrapping `input` elements with paragraphs.

Comment: am not sure this is what you excepted http://jsfiddle.net/wsh58zb6/1/

Comment: Or this - http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/wsh58zb6/5/

Comment: or with the Bootstrap Syntax http://jsfiddle.net/wsh58zb6/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap has built in classes for this...

```
<div class="column col-sm-12">

  <div class="form-horizontal">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Test</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <select class="form-control">
          <option>test1</option>
          <option>test2</option>
          <option>test3</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">LongLineTest</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <select class="form-control">
          <option>test1</option>
          <option>test2</option>
          <option>test3</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div> <!-- form-horizontal -->

</div>
```

[DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/aHdZApV0wg)

[DOCUMENTATION](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal)

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your content into another div and add `text-align:right;` [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wsh58zb6/6/)

Comment: your fiddle not give a solution its breaked

Answer (score 0):

```
   <div class="row" style="margin:10px 0px 10px 75px;">
```

adjust accordingly.
Enjoy buddy